# odata class generation from edmx model

Tags: c#, odata, edmx

I am trying to work with data from an existing ODATA endpoint in code for another ODATA API.

I have no desire to recreate all the models manually and so I was hoping to use the existing edmx models to create the classes in C# that I need.

I looked into the "odata client code generator" offered by Microsoft and this seems like the perfect solution, but I can only get it to work if I connect directly to a service endpoint... it doesn't work if I download the edmx file and try to use that (even though the tutorial says you can use a URL OR a file).

Has anyone actually been able to successfully connect this odata client code generator to an edmx file?

If I can't get this working, does anyone have other suggestions for how to generate the classes I need from these edmx models?

I am specifically trying to work with the metadata from Microsoft Project Online.  It gives an endpoint like this:
https://[domain]/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/$metadata

I can't connect directly to this unfortunately because it requires authentication and the odata client code generator doesn't support authentication...

Comment: Have you looked at following msdn webpage? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/entity-data-model-tools-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: I've read up on edmx files, but I'm unable to open the ones I have in visual studio for some reason that's not entirely clear to me

Comment: honestly my main question is how to get the odata class generation tool to work with edmx files and that link doesn't say a word about that and the docs for the odata class generation tool are quite limited as are most microsoft docs

Comment: Can't you copy the file locally and then modify the project configuration file to point to the local copy?

Comment: yes, and it appears to work, but the generated file doesn't contain anything... after a lot of headache on this matter it appears that VS 2017 just isn't supported for this tool... though they certainly don't make that very clear... I am testing with VS 2015 now to see if that resolves my issues

Comment: It has nothing to do with VS..  It has to do with version of Net.  It is in Net 4.7.2 and if you target the project for 4.7.2 you should have the feature.

Comment: this particular problem is most certainly a visual studio issue... changing .NET versions doesn't affect whether or not I have access to the OData client code generation tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears VS 2017 is not supported by the odata client code generation tool.  I am trying out VS 2015 now.

Edit:
I have confirmed that the client code generation tool works with visual studio community 2015.  I couldn't get it to work because I was running it under visual studio professional 2017... Microsoft employees have reported on a couple of forums that this tool isn't support under VS 2017.

Also, I found out this this service still won't work with the OData client code generator anyway since it is OData V3 and the tool only works with OData V4.  You must use DataSvcUtil.exe to generate code from earlier versions of OData.  I downloaded the .edmx file and run the following command to generate the classes:

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\DataSvcUtil.exe" /dataservicecollection /version:2.0 /language:CSharp /out:TestOutput.cs /in:C:\Users\[username]\DevelLocal\test1.edmx
```

Comment: I still cannot get it to work with my edmx file using the DataSvcUtil.exe, it also generates an C# class with only the header comment.  Is there more secret to this sauce?

Comment: what version of OData is the endpoint you are working with? are you specifically trying to work with Microsoft Project Online data like I was or is your edmx file for something else?  the answer I mentioned above is only working for OData V1 - V3

Comment: I have yet to get the models to build.  So, I've decided to use Restier to host the services from my existing EF EMDX file.  I'm having some progress, but still not there yet.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja - what was the outcome w/Restier and consuming a static EDMX?

Comment: This was many moons ago.  I barely remember posting this.